# How to Manage Transaction across sequences in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have 2 `sequences in my ESB` namely "seqDeleteEntry" and "seqInsertEntry" respectively.

The sequence "`seqDeleteEntry`" will remove entry from table based on the input received.
**Code snippet:**

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="propertyName" expression="//Id/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <transaction action="new"/>
   <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>       
         <dbreport useTransaction="true">
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <password>$pwd</password>
                  <user>$uname</user>
                  <url>connectionURL</url>
                  <driver>$driver</driver>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>
                  <![CDATA[ delete from tbl_name where column_name = ?]]>
               </sql>
               <parameter expression="$ctx:propertyName" type="VARCHAR"/>
            </statement>
          </dbreport>
          <sequence key="conf:/seqInsertEntry"/>
   </sequence>
```

The sequence "`seqInsertEntry`" will insert entry into table.
**Code snippet:**

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">     
             <dbreport useTransaction="true">
                <connection>
                   <pool>
                      <password>$pwd</password>
                      <user>$uname</user>
                      <url>connectionURL</url>
                      <driver>$driver</driver>
                   </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                   <sql>
                      <![CDATA[ insert into tbl_name values('value1', 'value2')]]> 
                   </sql>
                </statement>
              </dbreport>
              <transaction action="commit"/>
              <send/>
       </sequence>
```

**My Question is:**
When there is error(say `Integrity Constraint Violation`) while inserting entry in the second sequence(`seqInsertEntry`), I need to rollback the transaction in such a way that the record deleted using previous sequence(`seqDeleteEntry`) should restored.

What configuration I need to add to implement transaction management in the above sample?

**Note:**
I tried setting the following property but it doesn't help.

```
<transaction action="new"/>
<property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

And I have added the following attribute in `DBReport`(in both the sequences) and committed the transaction at the end of second sequence(`seqInsertEntry`) and still it doesn't help.

```
useTransaction="true"
```

Someone please clarify what configuration I missed or I need to add in the above sequences.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer documentations [1] and [2]...

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Transaction+Mediator+Example

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Transactional+ESB

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: Hi Mohan, Thanks for the link... I looked into the documentation given in the above links. But it doesn't help me. In the above documentation, the delete and insert(through DBReport) are in same sequence whereas in my case they are in different sequence. Also I tried implementing "faultSequence" as in the link which also doesn't help. I think the transaction is not carried to the sequence that I am forwarding to. Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Vijay, my understanding is that transactions are not carried across sequences, except in fault sequences (and when the error is raised synchronously). Transactions appear to be attached to a sequence and client.

How did you implement your fault sequence?

If I am wrong about cross-sequence transactions, I would be grateful to know how this can be achieved :-)